# Why is row affected 0 in this SQL Server query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008. Here is what I'm trying to do. I have a table with marketgroupID and parentID. each marketgroup has a name. I'd like to create the hierarchy path of those names.

I tried the CTE solution with a WITH anchor_statement recursive_statement, select. it didn't work.

I found another solution where you create a new table, and fill in the values iteratively. It's not the most performant, it duplicates lots of data and columns, but i don't really care because it's more or less a one time process on a relatively small database. I'm just looking for a simple solution (like everyone I guess)

Basically, I successfully created the table and copied some values inside of it.

```
--Create Lineage Table
Create Table Eve.dbo.invLineage(
Node int NOT NULL IDENTITY(100,1),
typeID int,
parentNode int,
marketGroupName nvarchar(100),
marketGroupID int,
Depth tinyint,
Lineage nvarchar(max)
)
```

and copied values into it.

```
INSERT INTO EVE.dbo.invLineage ( typeID,marketGroupID)
SELECT [EVE].[dbo].invTypes.typeID,EVE.dbo.invTypes.marketGroupID
FROM EVE.dbo.invTypes
LEFT JOIN eve.dbo.invGroups ON EVE.dbo.invTypes.groupID= eve.dbo.invGroups.groupID
WHERE eve.dbo.invGroups.categoryID=7 AND Eve.dbo.invTypes.published=1
```

this is an exemple of the result I get at this stage:

```
 Node   typeID   parentNode marketGroupName marketGroupID Depth Lineage
 100    377      NULL       NULL            605           NULL  NULL
 101    380      NULL       NULL            605           NULL  NULL
 102    393      NULL       NULL            126           NULL  NULL
 103    394      NULL       NULL            126           NULL  NULL
 104    399      NULL       NULL            609           NULL  NULL
 105    400      NULL       NULL            609           NULL  NULL
 106    405      NULL       NULL            604           NULL  NULL
 107    406      NULL       NULL            604           NULL  NULL
```

So I managed to get a nodeID, a typeID, and a marketGroupID successfully. sorry for the bad display in here, I'm still learning the forums.

Now, I'd like to update the parentNode for each row of the Lineage table.

This information is a column in the marketGroup table.

Here is the request I wrote but that returns 0 rows.

```
UPDATE T SET T.parentNode=P.Node
FROM Eve.dbo.invLineage as T 
INNER JOIN eve.dbo.invMarketGroups E ON T.marketGroupID=E.marketGroupID
INNER JOIN eve.dbo.invMarketGroups B ON E.parentGroupID=B.marketGroupID
INNER JOIN Eve.dbo.invLineage P ON B.marketGroupID=P.marketGroupID
```

The first 2 inner joins seems to work fine, but the last one makes it return 0 rows.

Also, I'm following this handy guide : http://www.sqlteam.com/article/more-trees-hierarchies-in-sql

Here are some results i get if i run this select query for debug purpose:

```
SELECT * --SET T.parentNode=P.Node
FROM Eve.dbo.invLineage as T 
INNER JOIN eve.dbo.invMarketGroups E ON T.marketGroupID=E.marketGroupID
INNER JOIN eve.dbo.invMarketGroups B ON E.parentGroupID=B.marketGroupID
--INNER JOIN eve.dbo.invLineage P ON B.marketGroupID=P.marketGroupID

Node    typeID  parentNode  marketGroupName marketGroupID   Depth   Lineage marketGroupID   parentGroupID   marketGroupName description iconID  hasTypes    marketGroupID   parentGroupID   marketGroupName description iconID  hasTypes
1134    10039   NULL    NULL    760 NULL    NULL    760 9   Civilian Modules    Modules whose specifications are geared toward use on rookie ships. NULL    1   9   NULL    Ship Equipment  Everything the dedicated pilot needs to outfit their ship.  1432    0
2913    21853   NULL    NULL    760 NULL    NULL    760 9   Civilian Modules    Modules whose specifications are geared toward use on rookie ships. NULL    1   9   NULL    Ship Equipment  Everything the dedicated pilot needs to outfit their ship.  1432    0
```

Comment: Are there any rows in the `invMarketGroups` table with a matching marketGroupID?

Comment: If you do a SELECT on the first two ineer joins, what do you get?  Can you show us the data?  To me the simple answer is `There are no B.marketGroupID that match any of your P.marketGroupID`...

Comment: i believe yes. i could show you some results.

Comment: @user1336586 Dems explains my question more succinctly

Comment: Like @Dems said, turn the UPDDATE into a SELECT, and run it joining the first two tables, and then try it with all three.

Comment: i added results in the original post. still having trouble tabbing the stuff so it displays correctly.

Comment: @user1336586 Use spaces not tabs, In SQL Server output results to text (Ctrl+T), select and paste as code in your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your records have `B.marketGroupID = 9`.

But your `eve.dbo.invLineage` table only has `marketGroupID IN (605, 126, 209, 604)`

So, in short, you get no records because `ON B.marketGroupID=P.marketGroupID` never finds any matches.

Comment: although i only showed 3 lined out of many, your comment is still true. somehow when i copied the data into the table, i limited my search too much.

Comment: i will move on by modifying marketGroups directly. Thank you.